# Does C++ guarantee that the address of base and derived references are equal?

Tags: c++

Does C++ guarantee that the address of base and derived references are equal?  I've written some code that seems to work based on this assumption, but I would like to get confirmation.  If it is guaranteed, it would be icing on the cake if anyone can point to a section of the standard that I've overlooked.  Thanks in advance.

**Example**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

struct Base {
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

struct Derived : Base {
    virtual ~Derived() {}
};

int main() {
    Derived derived;
    Base &base = derived;
    std::map<void*, int> testMap;
    testMap[&base] = 0;
    if (testMap.count(&derived) > 0) {
        std::cout << "addresses match\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not when you have multiple inheritance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the spec actually explicitly says they're not guaranteed to be equal.

Comment: I think it would work if you made it be `map<Base *, int>`, or if you cast `&derived` to `Base *` before using it as a map key.

Comment: FWIW if you `dynamic_cast<void*>` you're guaranteed to get the address of the most-derived object, which therefore is the same for both even with multiple inheritance. I can't remember if there's a special guarantee for single inheritance or not, but I'm entirely prepared to believe Mooing Duck that there explicitly isn't.

Comment: You'll probably get such a guarantee for standard-layout types (where there may not be any padding at the beginning). However, your types are not standard-layout since they contain a virtual function (-> vtable).

Comment: You don't always need ISO-standard-clad assurance. Sometimes what is acceptable is "it works with these four compilers for these six platforms we are targetting".

Comment: @Mysticial: Thanks for bringing up multiple inheritance.  That helped me prevent a bug that I would likely encounter in the future.

Comment: @SteveJessop:  Thanks for your input.  Mentioning dynamic_cast led me to search based upon that keyword and eventually find N3337, Section 5.2.7, Paragraph 7, which confirms that "...the result is a pointer to the most derived object pointed to..." A modified revision of my test using dynamic_cast with multiple inheritance seems to confirm.  Also, if you post an answer, I'll select it.

Comment: @Kaz: I feel that approach may leave one eventually saying "It no longer works on the current compiler release."  Also, ISO-standard-clad assurances are quick debate-enders during code review.

Comment: @Kaz - true but one needs to keep in mind that a future version of one of those compilers may break things.

Comment: This is also not the case with `virtual` inheritance, even if it's not multiple.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no such guarantee for base classes in general. If you set up the right combination of base classes for `Derived` then it's pretty much guaranteed that the base class pointers *can't* all be the same address as the `Derived` pointer.

Since your classes have at least one virtual function, you can use `dynamic_cast<void*>` to get the address of the most-derived object. This is the same regardless of which type in the hierarchy you start from.

Comment: The address of an object is the address of the object regardless of anything. I don't see how this answers the question begun asked.

Comment: @EJP: you are mistaken. If `B` has two base classes `A1` and `A2` by multiple inheritance, and `b` is an instance of `B` then in general `(void*)(A1*)(&b)` differs from `(void*)(A2*)(&b)`, hence one of them differs from `(void*)(&b)`. Therefore "the address of the object" is *not* the same regardless of anything, it makes a difference which base class sub-object you start from. You may not care about the difference (perhaps you're not starting from a base class sub-object), but the questioner does (and is) or wouldn't be asking whether this guarantee exists.